# RSpec let with string and hash - syntax error

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to have let which in result I'll have:

```
("project = TSW-123 AND status != Done AND status != Closed AND status != Cancelled AND status != Followup", {:max_results=>1000, :start_at=>0})
```

My let:

```
  let(:jql_options) do
   "project = TSW-123 AND
    status != Done AND
    status != Closed AND
    status != Cancelled AND
    status != Followup",
    {
      start_at => 0,
      max_results => 1000
    }
  end
```

With error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
      status != Followup",
```

Comment: What do you want your `let` statement to return? What's your question?

Comment: You should wrap that on `[]`.

Comment: @MarekLipka Exactly what I wrote in the first line. I've got a method where in parameters I want to pass this string and the hash e.g. `method("string", { key: value })` - this let represents those passing params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `let` to return an array:

```
let(:jql_options) do
  [
    "project = TSW-123 AND status != Done AND status != Closed AND status != Cancelled AND status != Followup",
    {
      start_at => 0,
      max_results => 1000
    }
  ]
end
```

Comment: I've passing this let as a params in my method - e.g. `method("string", { key: value })` so it can't be `[]`

Comment: It can, all you have to do is use splat operator: `method(*jql_options)`.